# Call to undefined method stdClass::show()

Tags: php

I've been racking my brain for the past few hours trying to figure out why I'm encountering this error. You know what they say, when Google fails, Stack Overflow. Any and all help is appreciated, and my headache will thank you. :)

**Error Message**

```
Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::show() in /application/controllers/Dashboard.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 /system/Router.php(41): Dashboard->index()
#1 /index.php(39): CP_Router->loader()
#2 {main}
```

**index.php** - Responsible for bootstrapping the system.

```
define('CPBASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');
require_once(CPBASE . 'system/Controller.php');
require_once(CPBASE . 'system/Registry.php');
require_once(CPBASE . 'system/Router.php');
require_once(CPBASE . 'system/View.php');

function __autoload($class_name) {
    $filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.php';
    $file = __SITE_PATH . '/model/' . $filename;

    if (file_exists($file) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    include ($file);
}

$registry = new CP_Registry();
$registry->router = new CP_Router($registry);
$registry->router->setPath(CPBASE . 'application/controllers');
$registry->view = new CP_View($registry);
$registry->router->loader();
```

**view.php** - Responsible for generating the output.

```
class CP_View {
    private $registry;
    private $vars;

    function __construct($registry){
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value){
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    function show($name){
        $path = CPBASE . 'views/' . $name . '.php';

        if(file_exists($path) == false){
            throw new Exception('View not found: ' . $path);
            return false; 
        }

        foreach($this->vars as $key => $value){
            $$key = $value;
        }

        include($path);
    }
}
```

**dashboard.php** - The controller that calls the view.

**Note:** $this->registry is handed to the Dashboard controller through CP_Controller.

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CP_Controller {
    function __construct(){

    }

    public function index(){
        $this->registry->view->title = 'CPMVC';
        $this->registry->view->show('index');
    }   
}
```

Comment: There is no `show()` method on a `strClass()` object

Comment: Show the definition of the `CP_Registry` class

Comment: Are you sure that a view object is also defined as an attribute of `CP_Registry` Class? If it was, I couldn't understand the reason why the $registry is also defined in `CP_View` class as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is how the error comes about:

1. `$this->registry->view` is not set, so is initially `null`
2. You assign to it as though it's an object (`$this->registry->view->title = 'CPMVC';`) so PHP creates a `stdClass` object for you
3. You attempt to call the method `show` on this object, but a `stdClass` object has no methods.

The root cause is that either `$this->registry` itself is not being assigned when it should be (e.g. you are missing a call to `parent::_construct` which would set it, or you've marked it `private` rather than `protected`); or the registry object doesn't have a `view` property (entirely possible, as you haven't shown that code).

Comment: You're absolutely right I failed to pass along the registry object. If I declare `parent::__construct()` it would require passing along `$registry` into the parent constructor. What would be the best way to pass along the object?

Comment: @ThomasLDurbin I don't understand the question. You pass it along by accepting it as a parameter and passing that parameter along: `public function __construct($registry) { parent::__construct($registry); }` Of course, if that's *all* the constructor's doing, then you can just not specify a constructor in the child class at all, and let it be inherited from the parent like any other method.